# How to make the Barrier position accurate when using constrainedWidth？

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="text1,text2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my layout code, I want to use a Barrier to constrain other widet, the Barrier depends on the bottom of text1 and text2, the text in text2 may be multi-line, so constrainedWidth = true is used here, but this will cause Barrier The location is wrong, how can I fix this problem？

I tried setting text2 to layout_width="0dp", at which point the barrier's position is correct, but text2 may only have a few strings and I have to make its width wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Add `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` in `text2`. This will move the barrier along with the height. Heres the updated code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="TestTestTestTestTestTestTemmstsakdjnkjdaskjkashdkjahsdjhaksdjhjasdhkjahskjashdkjskdjhTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="text1,text2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: ```<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Test" />```
But this will cause the parent layout to crop other controls. For example, if I add a button like this, and make parent layout height wrap. if there is no app:layout_constrainedHeight="true", it will not be cropped.

Comment: what kind of behaviour you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the -20dp to be wrapped by the parent layout, not cropped